# Getting the minimum from elements of a Numpy array and a float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, min

Problem: I want to compare each element of a Numpy array with a float, returning an array with the smaller value. For example, using the inputs:

```
import numpy as np
input_a = 3
input_b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

the output should be

```
output = np.array([1,2,3,3,3])
```

My current solution is working by making a new np.array with only the constant, then using np.minimum().

```
c = np.copy(input_b)
c.fill(input_a)
output = np.minimum(input_b, c)
```

However, I am afraid that this is not the most efficient solution. Is there a more elegant / efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [logical indexing.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
import numpy as np
input_a = 3
input_b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

input_b[input_b > input_a] = input_a

print(input_b)
# [1 2 3 3 3]
```

`input_b > input_a` will return a mask array of either True or False values, where in this case the element will be True if the corresponding element in `input_b` is greater than `input_a`. You can then use this to index `input_b` and modify only those values.

Note that using logical indexing is quicker than using `numpy.where` for this particular array, though I can't tell you why exactly.

```
setup = 'from __main__ import np, input_a, input_b'
print(timeit.timeit('input_b[input_b > input_a] = input_a', setup=setup)) 
# 2.2448947575996456
print(timeit.timeit('np.where(input_b < input_a, input_b, input_a)', setup=setup)) 
# 5.35540746395358
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `np.minimum` is fine for this operation:

```
>>> np.minimum(input_b, 3)
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

If you want to modify `input_b` directly, use the `out` keyword argument to fill `input_b` with the pair-wise minimum values.

```
>>> np.minimum(input_b, 3, out=input_b)
>>> input_b
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

This is quicker than using boolean indexing and then assigning values:

```
>>> %timeit input_b[input_b > input_a] = input_a
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.16 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np.minimum(input_b, 3, out=input_b)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.53 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a builtin to do this: `clip`

```
output = input_b.clip(max=input_a)
```

or if you want set `input_b` itself

```
np.clip(input_b, None, out=input_b)
```

Here it's doing the same as `minimum`, but it can also do `maximum` in the same call.  Some versions accept the `max` keyword, others don't.

`clip` has a modest edge over `minimum` in my timings.  But I'd recommend which ever one seems clearest in intent.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner for this would be to use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(input_b < input_a, input_b, input_a)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.])
```

Here we pass `numpy.where` three arguments, where the first is a boolean array of where `input_b < input_a`. Whenever the value in this first argument is `True`, we take the value at the corresponding index from the second argument (`input_b`). Otherwise we take the value of `input_a`.

**Edit**: In fact, as @Kasra's answer shows, you can pass `input_a` directly without converting it to an `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
>>> np.where(input_b < input_a, input_b, input_a)
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```